# doesn't wrap the text in the textbox in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

[image]Got stuck up with wrap the text when user enters in the text box,used "MaxWidth to control the text box and wrap the text but it shrink the textbox size.am not sure how i have to strecth it,eventhoug am using HorizantalAlignment ="Stretch" but it doesn't match with the other text box.

If i don't wrap the text then the whole grid is moving to if the text is larger than the text box,is this anyway to fix the size and wrap the text please.

Here is my xaml code

```
  <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid Name="gLeftContent" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <!-- Row 14 -->
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBox 
                Name="tbName" 
                Text="{Binding SelectedStory.Slug, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" 
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=tbName}"   **//used ActualWidth but it shrinks the text box and doesn't match with the other text box.**
                Grid.Column="1" 
                Grid.Row="5" 
                TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                d:LayoutOverrides="Height" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                LostFocus="tbSlug_LostFocus"
                >
                 <TextBox 
                Name="tbHeadline" 
                Text="{Binding SelectedStory.Headline, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" 
                Grid.Column="1"  
                Grid.Row="6" 
                TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                d:LayoutOverrides="Height" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                LostFocus="tbHeadline_LostFocus" 
                 />
                </TextBox>
                <ItemsControl 
                Grid.Column="1" 
                Grid.Row="14" 
                Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MetadataGenerateImagesRegion}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start again with a clean answer:

```
        <TextBox Name="tbName"  
        Text="{Binding SelectedStory.Slug, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}"  
        Width="Auto" Height="Auto"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="5"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"  AcceptsReturn="True"  
        LostFocus="tbSlug_LostFocus" >
```

Please replace it entirely in your code to avoid any omision.

Comment: tbSlug belongs to Slug TextBox.Shown in the image on the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the RowDefinition Height="Auto" do it can grow to fit additional lines.

Definitely should not be binding width to itself.

Try

```
 <TextBox 
            Name="tbName" 
            Text="{Binding SelectedStory.Slug, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Grid.Row="5"  
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            LostFocus="tbSlug_LostFocus" />
```

Comment: After replace your code,it doesn't wrap the text rather than it stretch the size

Comment: Is there enough text that it should wrap?  Is the TextBox the proper width?   Take out the HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch".

Comment: tried pretty much all option look like my width causing the problem bcoz am using  <Grid Name="gLeftContent" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

Comment: Did you set the RowDefinition Height="Auto" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your textbox:

```
AcceptsReturn="True"
```

Although your control may present wrapped text, currently it is unable to accept enter keystrokes.

Comment: Thanks Jaime,it wraps the text but it shrink the size of the text box,am not sure why ?

Comment: do you have any previous style for TextBoxes? Despite of that, you can try with fixed width (as column's width) or Width="Auto"

Comment: i don't even find the "AcceptsEnter" property.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It is AcceptsReturn, I will correct my answer

Comment: i just upload the image for that text box "slug" when add this property "Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=tbName}" then it shrinks from the normal size

Comment: I can see that you stated:  `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=tbName}"` inside tbName  so you are refering yourself. Shouldn't be `ElementName=tbHeadline` ?

Comment: ElementName=tbName is the text box for "Slug" ,ElementName=tbHeadline for textbox "Headline".Its two different one.

Comment: Usher, check your code carefully, you are self-referencing in `<TextBox Name="tbName" Width={Binding .... ElementName=tbName`

Comment: That's correct Jaime, this is the actual code to avoid confusion  Name="tbSlug" 
                Text="{Binding SelectedStory.Slug, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" 
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=tbSlug}"

Comment: no, it doesn't make sense to bind your width to your self actualwidth

Comment: Oooh okie, when i remove that,it will not wrap the text anymore. eventhough i have TextWrapping="Wrap" .I read in the forum if use width="*" then it wont work

Comment: i can't thank you enought Jaime for your wonderful help but still am stuck with ground zero.